# JSON to HTML Table with JS No final output

Tags: javascript, html, json, html-table

I'm trying to add on to an html table with JS that gets info from a JSON file. 
I can't find out why this wont show any data on the table.

**JSON Example**

```
[{"User_Name":"John Doe","score":"10","team":"1"},
 {"User_Name":"Jane Smith","score":"15","team":"2"},
 {"User_Name":"Chuck Berry","score":"12","team":"2"}];
```

**My JS that is not working :(**

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="date">Date</th>
        <th data-field="message">Message</th>
        <th data-field="votes">Votes</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 window.onload = function(){
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("/crestdale/new/db.json", function(raw){
        console.log(raw);
    var json = raw;
    var tr;
    console.log(json);
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].date + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].message + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].votes + "</td>");
        $('table').append(tr);
    }
 });
    });
 };
 </script>
     </tr>
 </thead>
 </table>
```

#### **New Issue!!!!**

I have a php file that writes to the json file, when I try to use this script to add to the json file, it makes the json file not display.

**PHP**

```
<?php 
date_default_timezone_set('America/new_york');
$message = $_POST['message'];
$date = date("F j, Y, g:i a"); 

$fp = fopen('db.json', 'r+');
// Loading existing data:
$json = file_get_contents("db.json");
$data = json_decode($json, true);

// Adding new data:
$data[3] = array('date' => $date, 'message' => $message, 'votes' => $votes);

 // Writing modified data:
 file_put_contents('db.json', json_encode($data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT));


fclose($fp);



?>
```

**JSON after PHP**

```
{"0":{"User_Name":"John Doe","score":"10","team":"1"},"1":{"User_Name":"Jane Smith","score":"15","team":"2"},"2":{"User_Name":"Chuck Berry","score":"12","team":"2"},"3":{"date":"February 16, 2015, 11:06 pm","message":null,"votes":null}}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: No errors what so ever.... @ChrisPietschmann

Comment: Why are you adding `.date`, `.message`, `.votes` while your JSON sample has `User_Name`, `score` and `team`? Also, off topic, but you're driving some people crazy as you: 1) put `$(document).ready` inside `window.onload`; 2) put `<script>` directly inside `<tr>`.

Comment: If you are getting JSON you shown in example, then it does not have same properties as you are trying to read in javascript.

Comment: Are your `console.logs` print out values? Also try `$('.table')`

Comment: First, window.onload is redundant.  Second, you're doing a lot of jQuery stuff inside that `for` loop you really shouldn't.  Don't append anything anywhere until outside the for.  Just push it all into a temporary array, then join into a string, then append it all at once.  You also don't need this to be inside of your table HTML since you're doing it onDOMReady (aka `$(document).ready()`)  Also no reason to even have `json` at all since you don't do anything to `raw` differently.

Comment: @Deryck OP is using `$.getJSON` which should parse automatically. Agreed on the other points

Comment: The json was an example I had.. Sorry about all of the bad practices. I'm am open for any new way to get something slimier done. @Passerby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

db.json (Please notice no semicolon at the end ) In your post you specify a semicolon at the end of json file.

```
[{"User_Name":"John Doe","score":"10","team":"1"},{"User_Name":"Jane Smith","score":"15","team":"2"},{"User_Name":"Chuck Berry","score":"12","team":"2"}]
```

If you are using this directly on javascript it will work fine with semicolon.

```
var json = [{"User_Name":"John Doe","score":"10","team":"1"},{"User_Name":"Jane Smith","score":"15","team":"2"},{"User_Name":"Chuck Berry","score":"12","team":"2"}];
```

In a json file semicolon is illegal. But in javascript semicolon is the valid end of line of code. When we are using $.getJSON() it will get the json file content and parse it. Since semicolon is an illegal character ; parsing will be failed.

Your javascript is fine. But the problem is date,message,votes are not found on the Json. I've checked and this is working

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $.getJSON("db.json", function(raw){
            var json = raw;
            var tr;
            console.log(json);
            for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                tr = $('<tr/>');
                tr.append("<td>" + json[i].User_Name + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + json[i].score + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + json[i].team + "</td>");
                $('table').append(tr);
            }
         });
            });
```

### Solution to New Problem

are you sure $message and $votes get initialized properly.

```
    <?php 
         $date = date("F j, Y, g:i a"); 
         $message='new message';
         $votes=10;
         $contents = file_get_contents('db.json');
         $json  = json_decode($contents,true);
         $ar= array('date' => $date, 'message' => $message, 'votes' => $votes);
         array_push($json,$ar); 
         $newJson = json_encode($json);
         file_put_contents("db.json",$newJson);
    ?>
```

Comment: @bnussman parsing will be failed since it is an illegal character for Json.

Comment: One more question if you have the time.... Is there a way we can add brackets to the output of our php array? @Tintu C Raju  **THIS** `[{"3":{"date":"February 16, 2015, 11:42 pm","message":null,"votes":"Coming Soon"}}]`                           **Not This**  `{"3":{"date":"February 16, 2015, 11:42 pm","message":null,"votes":"Coming Soon"}}`

Comment: @bnussman  file_put_contents("j.json","[".json_encode($json)."]");

Comment: Oh no, Another question... On my table, my values are coming out as "undefined"... @Tintu C Raju

Comment: @bnussman  You have to use the same key names mentioned in json. That is why it displays undefined.  Make sure that the key names are the same.

Comment: Ok, and My JSON has the []'s at the very beginning and end, but that makes it display all as one entry. **Output** `[{"0":{"3":{"date":"February 16, 2015, 11:52 pm","message":"Hey!","votes":"Coming Soon"}},"3":{"date":"February 17, 2015, 12:03 am","message":"test","votes":"Coming Soon"}}]`    I kinda need the []'s between each data set.....  Oh, I also cant find out why I am still getting undfined... all of my key names match..

Comment: @bnussman change to this $ar[] = array('date' => $date, 'message' => $message, 'votes' => $votes); in time of writing json. You will get [ between each data set

Comment: didnt work @Tintu C Raju just added more []'s at the begenning and end. `[[[{"date":"February 17, 2015, 12:19 am","message":null,"votes":"Coming Soon"}],{"date":"February 17, 2015, 12:19 am","message":null,"votes":"Coming Soon"}]]`

Comment: still undefined info :(

Comment: @bnussman   i have checked it and its working fine for me...    http://pastebin.com/Z2CnJThC   Please check this contain the complete code i've tried.

Comment: I am getting an error with your array push... `Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /var/www/crestdale/new/write.php on line 14`

Comment: When i copy  your db.json, everything looks fine, my problem must be the writing to the json file...  @Tintu C Raju